# Git: Is there a merge strategy that will prevent me from having to resolve conflicts manually in this fairly simple case?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Scenario. I have a file like this in my main git branch:

```
A
B
```

One developer on branch `A` turns that into:

```
a
B
```

Another developer on branch `B` turns that into:

```
A
b
```

I want the result to be:

```
a
b
```

I know the A developer will not touch the B line and vice versa. They each have to maintain their own line in the file.

Is there a way to merge this without *manually* having to resolve conflicts so that in the end all have

```
a
b
```

Comment: Seems like a violation of the single responsibility principle. If two developers need to maintain different lines for different reasons you could consider splitting the file into multiple ones to avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: Yes, it is an uncommon case. There are files with translations and each line (or couple of lines) contains a text for a single language. Different translators work on different languages but they all see all the translations (which helps in deciding on their own).

Answer (score 1):

This is such an uncommon case, and is so dangerous in general, that there's no automation for it.

Your options here:

1. Make an editor macro to do it to the conflict under the cursor, which will make resolving these a subsecond affair;
2. Write a script to do it, to merge-by-combining all conflicts with only non-overlapping changed lines (but be warned: this is the so-dangerous case);
   or
3. Introduce a separator line between your `a` and `b` lines.